# Does Kotlin have a Result type like Swift

Tags: swift, kotlin, types

Swift has a `Result` type that is declared like this

```swift
enum Result<Success, Failure: Error> {
    case success(Success)
    case failure(Failure)
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```swift
enum FooError: Error {
    case fizzReason
    case barReason
    case bazReason
}

func returnResult() -> Result<String, FooError> { 
    // ... Just imagine this method returns an error
}

switch returnResult() {
case .success(let string):
    print(s)
case .failure(.fizzReason):
    // do something
case .failure(.barReason):
    // do something
case .failure(.bazReason):
    // do something
}
```

Does Kotlin have a similar Data Type which can be used in the same manner?

Comment: Here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't know whether Kotlin has something like that but here is an implementation that should do the same:

```
sealed class Result<out Success, out Failure>

data class Success<out Success>(val value: Success) : Result<Success, Nothing>()
data class Failure<out Failure>(val reason: Failure) : Result<Nothing, Failure>()
```

Actual example:

```
fun echoString(string : String) : Result<String, Exception> {
    return if (string.isEmpty()) {
        Failure(Exception("Error"))
    } else {
        Success(string)
    }
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    when(val result = echoString("string")) {
        is Success -> println(result.value)
        is Failure -> println(result.reason)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Kotlin has [Result](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/index.html#result) with properties such as [isFailure](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/is-failure.html) and [isSuccess](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/is-success.html) which basically equivalent to Result of Swift.

**Summary**

> Result, a type in the Kotlin standard library that is effectively a
>   discriminated union between successful and failed outcome of execution
>   of Kotlin function — Success T | Failure Throwable, where Success T
>   represents a successful result of some type T and Failure Throwable
>   represents a failure with any Throwable exception. For the purpose of
>   efficiency, we would model it as a generic inline class Result in
>   the standard library.

**[Limitation](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/result.md#limitations)**

Result cannot be used as a direct result type of Kotlin functions, properties of Result type are also restricted: e.g.

```
fun findUserByName(name: String): Result<User> // ERROR: 'kotlin.Result' cannot be used as a return type 
fun foo(): Result<List<Int>> // ERROR 
fun foo(): Result<Int>? // ERROR
var foo: Result<Int> // ERROR
```

However, functions that use Result type in generic containers or receive result as a parameter type are allowed:

```
fun findIntResults(): List<Result<Int>> // Ok
fun receiveIntResult(result: Result<Int>) // Ok
```

**[Usage(run online)](https://pl.kotl.in/hB-melMue)**:

```
class NumberNotEvenException(var number: Int) : Exception("$number not even") 

fun checkEvenNumbers(list: List<Int>): List<Result<Int>>{

    var returnList = mutableListOf<Result<Int>>()
    for (number in list){
        if (number%2==0){
            returnList.add(Result.success(number))
        }else{
            returnList.add(Result.failure(NumberNotEvenException(number)))
        }
    }
    return returnList
}


fun checkResult(result: Result<Int>){

    result.fold(onSuccess = { number ->
            println("$number is even")

    },onFailure = { 
        if (it is NumberNotEvenException){
            println("${it.number} is Odd")
          }
    })
}

fun main() {
    checkEvenNumbers((0..100).toList()).map {
            checkResult(it)
        }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if quotes with essential info from all links would be added directly to the question. Because hyperlinks tend to break and linked info can change.

Comment: The result type in the standard library is of very little practical use because it exists to solve a specific problem and can't be used generically - see here: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/result.md#limitations

Comment: As of Kotlin 1.5 these limitations are lifted and you can freely use Kotlin's Result monad in your code, no need to create your sealed class.

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple implementations, but the two that I'm aware of (and that I know to be actively maintained) are:

- [Kotlin-result](https://github.com/michaelbull/kotlin-result) - straight up result type, usefully flexible (there are references to other implementations in the README.md)
- [Either in Arrow](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core/arrow.core/-either/index.html) - a Kotlin implementation of Either which can be used as a result. ([Arrow](https://arrow-kt.io/) has lots of interesting functional stuff)